# QQuickImageProvider can have a stable 60 fps frame rate

Tags: linux, qt, qml

I have a QQuickImageProvider,

The frequency of the requestPixmap is not always stable. Sometimes the delta between 2 calls exceed 20 ms.

And a visual dropping effect can be observed on the screen.

Someone have an idea ? It's the good way to do that ?
Can I monitor or debug this ?

Thanks

Comment: an idea about what? the good way to do what? please clarify the question and provide [mcve]

Comment: Another (non tested) option may be to use a `VideoOutput` and implementing a custom [source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html#source-prop).

Comment: Why is the QQuickImageProvider being used to output images at a high frequency? What is the point? Are you generating an animation? Are you capturing and/or playing a video? There's a lot of context missing in this question.

Comment: It's quite difficult to have a reproducible code. Because, it's seems depending of the qml files, it seems more I have binding and stuffs, more it's unstable. 
I generate a video flux (and don't come from a file for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render frames at a high frequency, consider using another approach: create a custom QQuickItem and reimplement the updatePaintNode method: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickitem.html#updatePaintNode. As an alternative, you can also use a QQuickPaintedItem, but performance is slower: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickpainteditem.html.

In any case, note that it takes time to decode images (you don't say what is the source format) and upload to the GPU (you did not say the size). On some embedded systems, 20ms may be challenging.